# PIXI.extras.MovieClip catch end of loop

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am using PIXI.extras.MovieClip to play a short animation (about 60 frames) and due to not knowing how many FPS there will be on users device I can't tell how much time exactly does it take to play all the frames. setTimeout also does not guarantee that function will be triggered exactly after specified time so it's kinda not my way of solving this too.

When the playing of animation is finished I want to trigger some events in code to remove the MovieClip and write some logs.

The problem is that I can't find any kind of trigger/callback that will be called when last frame of animation was rendered.

example code:

```
movie = new PIXI.extras.MovieClip(someFrames);
movie.animationSpeed = 1;
movie.onComplete = animationFinished;
movie.play()

animationFinished = function () {
  console.log("Animation just reached it's end.");
  movie.gotoAndStop(0);
};
```

the obvious problem is, that movie.onComplete is never called. Is there any way to make this work?

Thanks for any suggestions and ideas.
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
movie = new PIXI.extras.MovieClip(someFrames);
movie.animationSpeed = 1;
movie.onComplete = animationFinished;
movie.loop = false;
movie.play();

animationFinished = function () {
    console.log("Animation just reached it's end.");
    movie.gotoAndStop(0);
};
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".